# Concatenating Quotes on to Variable in r

Tags: r

I'm new to r and I'm having trouble figuring out how to add quotes to a variable in a function so I can select the column in a dataframe.  The basic idea is below.  The problemn is concatenating the quotes on to the varialbe.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
function(col)
     {y<-data[,"col"]
      y
}
```

Comment: If you got whatever to 'work' ( and I do understand the downvote for lack of clarity), then you would  need neither the assignment nor the repetition of the "y" name. Simply putting in `data[ ,"col"]` would be sufficient. Functions return the result of the last evaluation.

Comment: You want to convert a column name to a character vector; it's not just "concatenating quotes" to it. See the manpage on [extract, or the \] operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `deparse`

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])

foo <- function(data, col) {
    data[, deparse(substitute(col))]
}

foo(dat, x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
foo(dat, y)
# [1] a b c d e
# Levels: a b c d e
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple example code:

```
test = data.frame(some_name = c(1, 2, 3))

your_func <- function(col) {
   y <- test[col]
   return(y)
}
your_func("some_name")
```

Is this what you mean? It seems a bit weird to want to add quotes, I guess you just failed to extract an element of the `data.frame`. In case you really want to concatenate quotes to a variable, you might want to look at `paste()`